# how to pass value to another php page using href

Tags: php

```
 <a href="project_description.php"> '.$row['status_title'].'</a>
```

I want to pass the value of '.$row['status_title'].' to "project_description.php"

Comment: Question is not correct, please describe what you need and show all part of code.

Comment: try googling first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value using GET method.

HTML

```
<a href="project_description.php?s_title=' . $row['status_title'] . '"> ' . $row['status_title'] . '</a>
```

PHP

```
$title = $_GET['s_title'];
echo $title;
```

Comment: Welcome @saujan. Please vote it if it is right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as a [URL parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
<a href="project_description.php?title=' . $row['status_title'] . '"> ' . $row['status_title'] . '</a>
```

And you can access the value using `$_GET['title']` within the `project_description.php` file.

Comment: how to call that url in another page

Comment: @saujan : what u mean ?? you can get the value using `$_GET['title']`

Comment: you don't need to call anything just echo $_GET['title'];  you will get the value . which is you passed as  query string  @saujan

Comment: yeah got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use query string as:-

```
<a href="project_description.php?key=value"> '.$row['status_title'].'</a>
```

**project_description.php** page get it like this

```
$value = $_GET['key'];
```

Comment: it wont work, i want to get the content of '.$row['status_title'].' which is string to another page. .$row['status_title']. generates new status_title everytime user submits the form

Answer (score 0):

Put the data in the `url` of your `href`

```
<a href="project_description.php?status_title=<?php echo $row['status_title']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['status_title']; ?></a>
```

Then use `$_GET[]` to get the value in the `url`

```
$var = $_GET['status_title'];
```

Comment: typo php tag <?php

Comment: ... and replace `Lorem Ipsum` with `<php echo $row['status_title']; ?>`, in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback